# Caching state with Grails controllers

Tags: grails, caching, model-view-controller, singleton, stateless

I understand that Grails strives very hard to be stateless, however I have a need for one of my controllers to retain a particular `fizz` value that should be found inside every HTTP request:

```
class MyController {
    List<Fizz> cachedFizzes = new ArrayList<Fizz>()

    def index() {
        Fizz fizz = extractFizz(params)
        cachedFizzes << fizz

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

However when testing this approach locally, it seems that `cachedFizzes` is re-instantiated with each HTTP request, and so no matter how many times I call one of this controller's actions, the list of `Fizz`es never grows.

So I ask: how can I (**specifically**) inject `MyController` with a `List<Fizz>` that will exist and grow across the lifetime of the *app* (not the controller/HTTP request)?

Comment: "I have a need for one of my controllers to retain a particular fizz value that should be found inside every HTTP request" - That sounds like a broken requirement. I expect that if you drill in and figure out what the actual requirement is, you will end up with a better solution.  There is no way for me to guess exactly what the actual requirement is but I would bet that it is probably more like you need access to a particular value inside of every request, not that the value needs to be maintained in an instance of a controller in particular, which is almost certainly the wrong thing to do.

Comment: The more common and less problematic thing to do often involves maintaining that state somewhere outside of the controller, like a singleton bean which could be but wouldn't have to be a Service.  You probably still want your controllers to be singleton, but not because that helps you do what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

There's rarely a need to create a new controller instance for each request, so it's best to configure them as singletons in `Config.groovy`:

```
grails.controllers.defaultScope = 'singleton'
```

But I think that's the default setting for Grails versions where this is configurable - what version of Grails are you using?

Another option that will work with singleton or instance-per-request controllers is to make cachedFizzes static.

Unrelated - `new ArrayList<Fizz>()` is way too verbose; just use `[]`. You'll still have the self-documenting collection and generic type on the left and it will function identically.